# jquery won't let me fade list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in jquery i tried to let items in my navbar fade with query but it isn't working.

here is my code html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TGT het Gamekanaal van Nederland</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Desktop/sites/tigametijd site/index/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="navbar">
        <ul id="fade">
            <li id="fade"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="fade"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li id="fade"><a href="../contact/contact.html">Contact ons</a></li>
            <li id="fade"><a href"">Over ons</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css code.

```
.navbar {
height:40px;
width:900;
margin:auto;
display:block;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}

#fade

{
list-style:none;
display:inline;
padding-left:107px;
opacity:0.7;
}
```

and here is my script code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.navbar').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.navbar').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
});
```

im just starting making my own website so if you see more things ive done wrong just tell me.

Comment: You cannot give same id to all <li> tags.

Comment: Unless it is inside `script.js`, you aren't loading the jQuery library. I am guessing that is your issue as your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/KMSE5/

Comment: your suffering from having duplicate id´s 

google for it, thats not valid

Comment: No need for two `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: If you want to continue using JS (you could just do this using CSS) you could add a [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to your animations, like `$('.navbar').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);`. This'll stop any currently running animations, so you won't get a fade in/out loop if the mouse rapidly enters/leaves the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JS should work for you. In the event functions, you'll want to use this [("The 'this' Keyword")](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/). Also, you can contain both event functions within the one doc ready container.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tvewk/)

Hope this helps!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });

    $('.navbar').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

***oGeez*** called it (and should get the upvotes, so go do it now), jQ is missing from the head. Add the jQuery library reference to your head and you should be good to go. Also, you'll want to make sure it comes before your script reference, otherwise it'll bork.

```
<head>
    <title>TGT het Gamekanaal van Nederland</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Desktop/sites/tigametijd site/index/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: this isn't working for me i can upload the .zip of the site (u may not finish it neither put it on the web)

Comment: In the comments of the question, user oGeez notes the issue correctly, a reference to the jQuery library needs to be included in the head before the script.js reference.

Comment: i did that but still got no effect

Comment: Can you post what Console is kicking back after interacting with the page? You can hit Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome and it will show you the errors happening. That will help to identify the culprit.

Comment: i temporarly disabled the animations with jquery and im to busy for now to put it back on so i see if i can do that later

Comment: Alright, just know that ctrl+shift+j is your homie when it comes to debugging JS issues. If it throws you for a loop, you can generally google the problem to get a good idea as to where to start.

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rt23m/2/)

You dont need JS, only CSS, if I'm right in thinking what you want, you can use:

```
.navbar {
    height:40px;
    width:900;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
.fade {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    padding-left:107px;
    opacity:0.2;
    transition:opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.fade:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Also note, `id` attributes **must be unique**, you should change your HTML to:

```
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul id="fade">
        <li class="fade"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="fade"><a href="#">Blog</a>

        </li>
        <li class="fade"><a href="../contact/contact.html">Contact ons</a>

        </li>
        <li class="fade"><a href "#">Over ons</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Additionally, `a` tags must have a valid `href` attribute, set to `#` if one isnt set.

Comment: i did it your way temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

i made it work i had some wrong src to the libraries i have now one to google an one to the query website and it works now so thanks for you help and ogees thanks thanks thanks.
it was your comment that i have been searching for libraries if there is a way i can give you reputation or something tell me.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing second (doc).rdy?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar').mouseenter(function() {
$('.navbar').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('.navbar').mouseleave(function() {
$('.navbar').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
});
```

Comment: this isn't working for me i can upload the .zip of the site (u may not finish it neither put it on the web)